# MassTransit Exceptions

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

What exceptions which should be handled in application would MassTransit throw?

I am using MassTransit with RabbitMQ.
I am wondering what exceptions we should catch from MassTransit.

Do you have anything like API document. (Hope it describe about errors)

Comment: What you are asking is not clear to me. Can you elaborate your question like what you want to achieve etc?

Comment: Thank you, Emre. I need to prepare that masstransit throws some exceptions. Where can I see to understand what exception the masstransit would throw? I need things like API documents.

Comment: You mean that exception thrown internally by masstransit, or exceptions thrown inside your consumer?

Comment: The exceptions are that thrown from masstransit internal. To prepare the masstransit throws exceptions, I want to put try-catch clause around masstransit calls. Therefore I want to get the information such as API documents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of exceptions that MassTransit may throw:

```
MassTransit.MessageData.DecodeException: Thrown when the message body cannot be decoded.
MassTransit.MessageData.EncodingException: Thrown when the message body cannot be encoded.
MassTransit.MessageData.MissingContentTypeException: Thrown when the message does not have a content type.
MassTransit.MessageData.NotFoundException: Thrown when the message cannot be found in the message data store.
MassTransit.MessageData.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Thrown when the message data has been modified since it was last read.
MassTransit.MessageData.StoreException: Thrown when an error occurs while storing or retrieving the message data.
MassTransit.MessageData.TooLargeException: Thrown when the message size exceeds the maximum allowed size.
MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.CircuitBreakerException: Thrown when the circuit breaker is open.
MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConcurrencyException: Thrown when the filter concurrency limit is reached.
MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.RetryException: Thrown when the filter retry limit is reached.
```

Note that this is not an exhaustive list and there may be other exceptions thrown by MassTransit depending on your specific implementation.

I would recommend reviewing the code and seeing if more exceptions have been added, and review if you need to catch them.

Remember exceptions are not Pokemon, you don't have to catch them all :)

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/search?q=throw&type=commits